# SQL Выборка из одной таблицы, исходя из другой таблицы

Tags: mysql, sql

Возникла проблема с составлением запроса mysql.

Есть 2 таблицы: 1я - название сериала, 2я - серии. В первой таблице поля "id", "title", во второй - "id", "serial_id", "title", "price".

**Table 1:**

```
id | title
-----------
 1 | title1      
 2 | title2
 3 | title3       
 4 | title4
```

**Table 2:**

```
id | serial_id |  title    | price
----------------------------------
 1 | 1         | demo text | 1100
 2 | 1         | demo text | 200
 3 | 2         | demo text | 450
 4 | 2         | demo text | 375
```

На сайте стоит сортировка по цене. Подскажите, пожалуйста, как сделать запрос, чтобы при выборе цены, показывались только те сериалы, цена серий которых удовлетворяет ограничению по цене!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Если нужно оставить сериалы, где хотя бы 1 серия удовлетворяет запрошенной цене:

```
select distinct t1.title, t2.serial_id
from table1 t1 inner join table2 t2 on t1.id = t2.serial_id
where t2.price < 400 /* тут задаём цену */
order by t1.popularity, t2.price /* desc по желанию */
```

---

Если нужно оставить сериалы, где хотя все серии удовлетворяют запрошенной цене:

```
select distinct t1.title, t2.serial_id, t2.id
from table1 t1 inner join (select serial_id, max(price) as max_price
                           from table2
                           group by serial_id
                           having max(price) < 1000 /* тут задаём цену */
                          ) t2 on t1.id = t2.serial_id
```

Comment: зачем тут использовать Left Outer Join, по определению не может быть записей в таблице серий с несуществующим вторичным ключем из таблицы сериалов

Comment: @IvanZakirov рабочая привычка, поправил

Comment: @Denis Требуется как раз первый вариант, спасибо! Тогда еще вопрос, например, сортировка стоит по цене и по популярности сериала. Популярность у нас в таблице "Сериалы", цена в таблице с сериями. Как сделать общую выборку?

Comment: Добавьте `ORDER BY t2.price, t1.popularity` в конец запроса.

Comment: @ВячеславФёдоров поправил, Arnial верно подметил

Comment: @Denis Все здорово, единственное, он выводит столько сериалов, сколько нашел подходящий серий, т.е. сериал может быть 1, а серий 10, и выведет 10 позиций, а нужно, чтобы 1

Comment: @ВячеславФёдоров не очень понял о чём вы, но попробуйте добавить `distinct`, ответ поправил

Answer (score 3):

```
SELECT
  t1.id,
  t1.title
FROM
  table1 t1,
  table2 t2
WHERE
  t1.id = t2.serial_id
  and t2.price between [min_price] and [max_price]
GROUP by
  t1.id,
  t1.title
```

Вместо BETWEEN, можно сделать и другие условия типа <> и т.д.

Answer (score 1):

```
$mysqli = new mysqli(/*данные для коннекта*/);
$cost = 100; //максимальная цена
$stmt = $mysqli->prepare("SELECT t1.title, t2.title, t2.price
    FROM table1 t1, table2 t2
    WHERE t1.id=t2.serial_id
    AND t2.price < ?");
$stmt->bind_params("i", $cost);
$stmt->execute();
```

Ну и так далее